# Function multiplication

Tags: functions

I was practicing the SAT, and everything correct but this one:
$f(x)=x^2+bx$, $g(x) = 3x^2-9x$
The functions $f$ and $g$ are defined above, where $b$ is a constant. If $f(x) * g(x) = 3x^4-8x^3-3x^2$, what is the value of $b$?

I did:
$(x^2+bx)(3x^2-9x)=3x^4-8x^3-3x^2$
Then, $3x^4-9x^2+3bx^3-9bx^2=3x^4-8x^3-3x^2$
I set $3bx^3=-8x^3$ and got $b=-\dfrac83$
or
$x^2(-9-9b)=-3x^2$ and got $b=-\dfrac23$.

Any help on this? It seems like a super easy problem, but I'm not sure how to get to the correct answer $\dfrac13$.

Answer (score 1):

Your second term of $-9x^2$ should be $-9x^3$.  Does that help?